# Cart and Checkout redirecting to 404

Tags: redirect, magento2.2.4, 404

I just updated to Magento 2.4, and I can't access my cart or checkout anymore. I see 500 errors, and a redirect to /noroute, bunt I can't figure out what's causing it.

Any way I can track this down further?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly change your Magento mode to "**developer**"

You can use following command to move in developer mode.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

after that try again with the cart and checkout page. you will see full log in **[Magento_root]/var/log/** folder.

Hiren Patel

Comment: I've done all of that. Multiple times

Comment: what did you get in log ?

Comment: I got something about Mageplaza layered navigation. I'm trying to disable that module, and try again

Comment: Okay , please share a error screenshot here so I can suggest something

Comment: I had a plugin that was set to disable cart and checkout for non logged in users. That's what I want, but it looks like customers aren't being logged in correctly, which is what's causing this issue.

New issue is that after login, customers are being redirected to checkout instead of back to the page they were on